# CefSharp DevToolsClient.Network event is not fired

Tags: .net, wpf, cefsharp

i'm tried to use DevToolsClient.Network event
but it not works.
i'm using WPF so
when browser's FrameLoadEnd event was fired, made DevtoolClient and register network event.

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            this.Browser.FrameLoadEnd += Browser_FrameLoadEnd; <----
        }

        private async void Browser_FrameLoadEnd(object? sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Frame.IsMain == false) return;
            if(devToolsClient == null)
            {
                this.Browser.ShowDevTools();
                devToolsClient = Browser.GetDevToolsClient();
                await devToolsClient.Network.EnableAsync();
                devToolsClient.Network.WebSocketClosed += Network_WebSocketClosed;<--- not fired
            }

        }

        private void Network_WebSocketClosed(object? sender, WebSocketClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

i tried all other network events.
how can use network's event?

Comment: Try running your application with the --disable-request-handling-for-testing command line argument. You'll likely need to disable CEFs request handling to get DevTools network events too fire. Also if you subscribe to the event after the socket is closed then the event won't fire.

Comment: You can post your own answer to help others.